# Problem with acronyms if order has been changed

Tags: glossaries

I wanted to change the order of acronyms to "ACRONYM (DESCRIPTION)" and found a solution in the forum. The problem is that it doesn't work for "plural acronyms" (the plural 's' is missing). How can I solve the problem?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries}

\AtBeginDocument{%
  \defglsdisplayfirst[\acronymtype]{%
    \glsentryshort{\glslabel} (\glsentrylong{\glslabel})#4%
  }%
}
\makeglossaries
\newacronym{PC}{PC}{Personal Computer}

\begin{document}
    \glspl{PC}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The simplest method is to just redefine `\acrfullformat` like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries}

\renewcommand{\acrfullformat}[2]{#2\space(#1)}

\makeglossaries
\newacronym{PC}{PC}{Personal Computer}

\begin{document}
    \glspl{PC}
\end{document}
```

This produces:

[image: PCs (Personal Computers)]

**Edit:**

For the record, as from version 4.02, there is another simple solution:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries}

\setacronymstyle{short-long}

\makeglossaries
\newacronym{PC}{PC}{Personal Computer}

\begin{document}
    \glspl{PC}
\end{document}
```

which again produces:

[image: PCs (Personal Computers)]